# How to move multiple files starting with different strings/names to different folder?

Tags: find, rename, mv

The scenario is I have a bunch of files:

`peter1.json`
`peter2.json`
`peter3.json`
`peter4.json`
`tom1.json`
`tom2.json`
`tom3.json`
`tom4.json`
`jane1.json`
`jane2.json`
`jane3.json`
`jane4.json`
plus various other files I don't want to move.

And I want to move those files into a folder called data. I tried variations on `mv peter* tom* jane* /data` and it doesn't work.

Am I using the wrong tool for the job? Should this be possible with `mv`?

At present I get a message:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Comment: Updated with output from Terminal

Comment: That's actually an interesting error to get, it's totally uninformative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like that's from the `mv` on Mac.

I'm guessing what you did was

```
mv peter* tom* jane* /data
```

while you meant `./data` or just `data`, i.e. to point at a directory in the current working directory, and not to one at the filesystem root.

If I try to move some files to a non-existing directory on a GNU system, I get the far more useful message:

```
$ mv foo bar /data
mv: target '/data' is not a directory
```

but indeed the `mv` on Mac just gives that useless usage guide, without bothering to tell what's actually wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was it!